# How does a document or application get displayed on the screen

Tags: operating-system, gpu, cpu, ram, drivers

I have got myself confused over how, lets say a word document, after being fetched by a controller and being placed in a specific place in memory gets displayed on the screen. This may be a very broad topic but i would like a general answer that i can then build on. (going back to the general answer if i get stuck).

I know it has got something to do with the CPU communicating with the GPU and drivers but this is as far as i can get without getting confused when reading articles about the subject.

Thanks in advance.